# Why does my JavaCC parser not parse tokens smaller than 2 characters?

Tags: java, parsing, bbcode, javacc

I'm working on a JavaCC parser that should parse BBcodes.

**My Javacc source code: [patebin.com](http://pastebin.com/1ZRj3fg2) (Junit test: [here](http://pastebin.com/ryzP8xv2))**

The source code kind off works, but it does not want to accept tokens with a single character, only multi character strings are recognized.

It does parse this string:

`"test[b]bold[/b]nothing[b]bold[/b]after"`

But not:

`"t[b]bold[/b]nothing[b]bold[/b]after"`

*I’m kind of lost here, any tips welcome here.*

Comment: While this most likely won't fix your problem, I notice in your grammar that you have `TEXT` set to `(<LETTER>|<DIGIT>|<PUNCT>|<OTHER>)*`. Should this not be `(<LETTER>|<DIGIT>|<PUNCT>|<OTHER>)+`, as the lack of text is not text (unless this was intended)?

Comment: @Paul, you’re right. I changed it back to ‘+’ as I initially had ‘+’ instead of ‘*’, it was just a desperate move to see if it changed behavior. BTW, it indeed did not help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the JavaCC syntax but looking at the `content()` part, does the `LOOKAHEAD(2)` preceeding the `text()` have any significance?  I'd guess that it should be `LOOKAHEAD(1)` or not there.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. You're right, it not needed (any more). But it did not fix my problem. The parser still does not match a single character tokens...

Comment: I'm inclined to think there's something wrong with the `body()` part.  Personally I write out all my grammar rules expanded and just have this feeling that the `*` might be causing some conflict.  Have you tried parsing just a single character string like `"t"`?  And a step above, a two character string?

Comment: @Jeff:It does parse 'tt' but not 't'. I also think it has something to do with the body or content rules. But I just can't figure out what... BTW it does not help to expand "body() <EOF>" to "(content())+ <EOF>"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.  Downloaded JavaCC and compiled everything.  With single character input, the output is:

```
String: t
Length: 1
Call:   parse
  Call:   body
  Return: body
Return: parse
Exception in thread "main" ParseException: Encountered " <LETTER> "t "" at line
1, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
    <EOF>
    "[b]" ...
    "[i]" ...
    "[u]" ...
    "[s]" ...
    "[url]" ...
    "[url=" ...
    "[img]" ...
    "[quote]" ...
    "[code]" ...
    "[color=" ...
    "[br]" ...
    <EOL> ...
    <TEXT> ...
    <TAGCHAR> ...
```

I noticed that it found a `<LETTER>` token but didn't recognize it as `<TEXT>`.

That's where the problem lies.  You've declared everything as tokens and based on the ordering of the token definitions, the string `"t"` is a `<LETTER>` first, not `<TEXT>`.  Move the `<LETTER>` token after `<TEXT>` and it should work now.  You'll want to apply the same changes for `<DIGIT>`s and other such tokens.

Comment: Jeff, thanks for all the work! I thought the error given was none descriptive, so I didn’t include it. Turns out, I just did not get it. I promise, next time I always include error messages. Thanks again, excelent!